# Bash Script to telnet network devices other then telnet port

Tags: bash, shell-script, networking, telnet

i have automate juniper auto add address  from one srx to another srx using script in virtual emulator.EVE-ng emulator set different telnet port for different network devices for telnet.
  eg, vsrx-1 telnet port will be 33025 and vsrx-2 will  be 33026.

i wanted to pass $var and $var3 through telnet to specific port eg. 33026.

```
telnet {  

while read -r line; do
var=`awk -v var1="^$line" -F "|" '$1~var1{print $1 }' sort-address-name-ip.txt | awk -v var2="$line$" '$0~var2' `
var3=`awk -v var1="^$line" -F "|" '$0~var1{print $2 }' sort-address-name-ip.txt`
    if [ $var =  $line ]
            then
            <pass $var and $var3 with more statements.>
            fi
    done < policy-unique_single_line-src-dst-ip.txt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i usually use i.e.

```
var1=`cat file`
var2= someother;
$host
$port
echo $var1 $var2 |telnet $host $port
```

So in your case i would give

```
telnet {  

while read -r line; do
var=`awk -v var1="^$line" -F "|" '$1~var1{print $1 }' sort-address-name-ip.txt | awk -v var2="$line$" '$0~var2' `
var3=`awk -v var1="^$line" -F "|" '$0~var1{print $2 }' sort-address-name-ip.txt`
    if [ $var =  $line ]
            then

            echo $var $var3 | telnet <$var-ip> <$var-port>

            fi


    done < policy-unique_single_line-src-dst-ip.txt
}
```

it a try

(sorry cant comment yet)

Comment: I tried this way but didn't work.
Script:
#!/bin/bash
#var1=`cat file`
var1= en;
var2=config t;
host=10.13.194.250
port=33029
echo $var1 $var2 |telnet $host $port

Output:
./telnet-stackflow.sh 
./telnet-stackflow.sh: line 3: en: command not found
./telnet-stackflow.sh: line 4: t: command not found
Trying 10.13.194.250...
Connected to 10.13.194.250.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.